# How-to build a droplet application in Xcode4?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, xcode4, applescript

In Xcode3 there used to be a template to build "Droplet" Applications (head/nibless apps that would throw whatever dropped at them at an "on open" Applescript method).

In Xcode4 this template is unfortunately gone.

What are the required steps to setup an xcode4 droplet project?

- modify the `info.plist` i guess to make the app handle drops
- get rid of the nib (also involves changes in `main.m` and both `AppDelegate.h` and `AppDelegate.m` i guess)

Maybe somebody even still has Xcode3 installed and could create an empty applescript droplet app and upload it somewhere? that would be very interesting. thanks!

(or is there maybe even a way to export an app bundle created with the AppleScript Editor to Xcode?)

Answer (score 1):

For a nibless droplet, you can always do that in the classic manner using AppleScript Editor:

```
to open(the_files)
    --Process each file here
end
```

Save as an application, and it'll be a droplet.

Comment: Actually, I believe it's `on open theItems`.

Comment: @NSGod: AppleScript accepts it with or without parentheses, and with the handler delimited by `to` or `on` (which are equivalent to each other).

Comment: Thanks. I know how to do it with the AppleScript editor. I am looking specifically for a way to rebuild the same functionality with a "real app" built via Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Making new templates in Xcode 4 (instead of just modifying an existing one) is quite a bit different from earlier versions and not really for the faint of heart.  You can make your own droplet easily enough by adding your specific document types or matching whatever (e.g. something like setting Extensions and Mime Types to *****), and adding a [application_openFiles_(sender, droppedItems)](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008592-CH1-SW37) handler to your application delegate.  You can delete the window from the xib, but other stuff in there is still used, such as the menu.

If you are running Lion, you can also create a Cocoa-AppleScript Applet directly from the **AppleScript Editor > File > New from Template** menu item, which has a minimal nib, is is already set up to handle dropped items, and includes code to use some of the regular AppleScript handlers such as **open**.  Debugging your application using this approach is more of a pain though, since it doesn't run in the editor environment (no log or console).

Comment: Thanks. I guess this comes close to what I am looking for. especially the application_openFiles_(sender, droppedItems) method. My problem however is that I have my problems to make it nib-less. When removing the nib (both the nib itself and the reference in Info.plist) I always run into the issue that Xcode complains "Could not connect the action buttonPressed: to target of class NSApplication".

Comment: The second method you mentioned comes closes to what I want, but unfortunately the "droplet" binary in the bundle created via the AppleScript Editor is already compiled. I am basically looking for a way to have a very simple project in Xcode thats equal to what Apple Script Editor generates when creating an App bundle.

Comment: The "compiled droplet binary" you are seeing in the MacOS folder is just the wrapper application that provides a shell for the Cocoa methods (similar to the AppleScript applet binary).  The CocoaAppDelegate.scpt in the Resources folder runs the script in the Scripts folder.